In SBT, retrieve the task result from all modules that the current module depends on
I found the way how to get all dependencies from current module:
val structure = buildStructure.value
val projectRef = thisProjectRef.value
val data = structure.data

val maybeProject = Project.getProject(projectRef, structure)

val aggregatesList = maybeProject
  .map(_.dependencies)
  .getOrElse(Seq.empty)

when I'm getting the settingKey value form result it works perfectly:
.map { ref =>
(ref.project / organizationName).get(data)

but it doesnt work with tasks, this code fails to be compiled by macro:
.map { ref: ClasspathDep[ProjectRef] =>
  (ref.project / publish / skip).get(data).map(_.value).get
}

How can I get task result from all subprojects?
